# Logstash configuration for returing single log line(containing pattern match) to the output

Tags: java

This is the requirement:
I want to monitor a log file, such that in case of any exception or pattern (which is defined in logstash filter) found in log file, then that specific log line in which pattern is found should get transmitted to defined output.

Now the problem is:
When logstash found that exception or specific pattern in log file, it returns the line in which that pattern was found, but it also returns all the tail -f(preceding) log lines.

I already tried with grok command but there wasn't any luck.

Is there any filter plugin, which returns only single line of log where the exact string match is found ignoring other lines.

I tried Google it, but again no luck :(